# How to check if an excel file cell has a certain value on load from datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, validation, loops, datagridview

I'm hoping to find a way to check if a certain cell in my excel file contains certain values.
Right now I'm pulling excel data into a datagridview in vb.net.
For instance, if only numbers are allowed in my cell but a letter is in place, I want the program to automatically change invalid entries to default values. Also I'm hoping to have an integer variable that increments by one if invalid entries are found.

Pseudocode:

```
First I need to define some type of integer variable named invalidcell,  
and initialize to 0.  
For each worksheet  
    For each cell in each worksheet 
        If an invalid cell is read then:
             the invalid cell value is replaced by the default value,  
             and the invalidcell is incremented by 1.
        End If
    End loop
End loop
```

Then when all the cells have been imported, display an error message if the invalidcell is > 0, that says how many invalidcells were found.

I greatly appreciate any help or suggestions anyone can give.

Comment: Do you want to open the workbook via Interop or just query it via Oledb? The latter is certainly faster

Comment: Then you can still use my answer below because the basic principle is the same. Use IsNumeric to check if the value is a number or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use `IsNumeric` to determine if it is a number or not. Then just declare a variable to count the invalid cell values.

```
Private Sub FillGridView()

'..Declare Excel application, workbook, range etc
Dim myValue as Integer = 0
Dim iCounter as Integer = 0
If IsNumeric(cell.Value2) Then
     'this is a number
     myValue = cell.Value2
Else
     'this is not a number - increment counter and set default value
     iCounter += 1
     myValue = 0
End If

If iCounter > 0 Then MsgBox(iCounter & " invalid cells were found.")

End Sub
```

and just add `myValue` to your grid view with whatever procedure you are using.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. One more thing, should I specify the cell value as a range of excel cells like so, "B2:E10"?

Comment: @stackexchange12 No. Taking the value of the range("B2:E10") would only return the calue of B2. You need to iterate through each cell in the range.